# La app que cree en android studio no abre en mi celular

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Quiero saber por que mi app que cree no abre en mi telefono, me sale el error de "por desgracia, contador vo se ha detenido."[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida celeste... Revisaste la info que devuelve el LogCat? Sería bueno saber que es lo que ocasiona que la app se cierre

Comment: Así sin saber con certeza que error te devuelve el log, te diría que revisaras que api de adnroid tiene tu movil y cual es la mínima en la que está desarrollada tu app(sdk minversion-- CREO QUE SE LLAMABA ASÍ). Puede que no te lo habra por eso.

Comment: Como ya te comentaron tal vez la aplicación es para android 8 por ejemplo y cel es versión 6 por ejemplo, eso puede ocasionar la falla.

Comment: Podrias subir el error que lanza el logcat?. o si no lo encontras ahi si vas a RUN tambien lo muestra

Answer (score 0):

hmm veo un error, tienes el codigo mal estructurado.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView txt_3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
        final EditText txt_2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String texto=txt_2.getText().toString();
                int contador = 0;
                char letra;

                for (int j = 0; j < texto.length(); j++) {

                    letra=texto.charAt(j);

                    if (letra=='a'|letra=='A'|letra=='e'|letra=='E'|letra=='i'|letra=='I'|letra=='o'|letra=='O'|letra=='u'|letra=='U') {
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                txt_3.setText("Hay "+contador+" vocales.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar las variables fuera del OnCreate()
Y referenciarlas con su ID dentro del OnCreate()

Ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 final TextView txt_3
 final EditText txt_2
 Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     txt_3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
     txt_2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_2);
     button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

     // La logica de tu app y demas
```

}